# Como separar array em ímpar/par e calcular número múltiplo?

Tags: php, array

Estou fazendo um *script* para separar número ímpar e número par de uma `array` inserida via opção de formulário, e fazer cálculo especifico sobre eles (para separar número ímpar do par da `array` estou usando `explode` e `implode` para colocar todas na mesma linha, porém o meu código está incompleto).

A minha dúvida é: Como calcular para que no resultado final o valor seja arredondado para um número múltiplo de 10?

**EXEMPLO:**
resultado final: 135

para ser múltiplo de 10, falta 5 , totaliza 140.

#### [Código:](http://pastebin.com/5BRSGPy5)

```
<?php
//separa os numeros da entrada da array retirando espaços vazios
$numUPC = explode(',', trim(trim($final_array), ',')); 
//final_array gerando erro undefined, motivo variavel sem entrada (Vazia)
 
$UPCdigito = array();
$numUPCpar = array();
$numUPCimpar = array();
$numArredondado = array();
 
//filtor de numero par e impar
foreach ($numUPC as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $numUPCpar[] = $value;
    } else {
        $numUPCimpar[] = $value;
    }
}
 
$numUPCpar  = implode(', ', $numUPCpar);
$numUPCimpar = implode(', ', $numUPCimpar);
 
//calculo
$numUPCimpar = array_sum($numUPCimpar);
$numUPCpar = array_sum($numUPCpar);
$UPCdigito = $numUPCimpar * 3;
$UPCdigito = $UPCdigito + $numUPCpar;
$numArredondado = (round($UPCdigito / 10, 0) )* 0.5
 
?>
```

A lógica do filtro de números ímpares e pares está correta? E como faço para identificar no meu resultado final quanto falta para o número ser múltiplo de 10?

Tentei usar `round`, porém está vago.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo da array de entrada?

Answer (score 2):

A verificação de par ou ímpar esta correta. Para arredondar para múltiplos de 10 pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
function round_multiple10_up($num) {
    $mod = $num % 10;

    if ($mod !== 0)
        return (10 - $mod) + $num;

    return $num;
}

function round_multiple10_down($num) {
    $mod = $num % 10;

    if ($mod !== 0)
        return $num - $mod;

    return $num;
}


$test = 144;

echo round_multiple10_up($test); //150
echo PHP_EOL;
echo round_multiple10_down($test); //140
```

Pode testar esse código neste link: http://ideone.com/L74t8w

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
O array original com os números
*/
$arr = [11,22,31,41,53,67,71,89,90,106];

/**
Organiza os números ímpares e pares num array.
O termo "even" significa "par", o termo "odd" significa "ímpar".
*/
foreach ($arr as $v)
    $rs[(($v % 2 == 0)? 'even' : 'odd')][] = $v;

/**
Verifica se existe o índice de números pares e aplica a soma total e o arredondamento para um múltiplo de 10. O arredondamento é sempre para cima.
*/
if (isset($rs['even']))
    $rs['sum']['even'] = ceil(array_sum($rs['even']) / 10) * 10;

/**
Verifica se existe o índice de números ímpares e aplica a soma total e o arredondamento para um múltiplo de 10. O arredondamento é sempre para cima.
*/
if (isset($rs['odd']))
    $rs['sum']['odd'] = ceil(array_sum($rs['odd']) / 10) * 10;

/**
Imprime o resultado, para depuração.
*/
print_r($rs);
```